# Javascript to jQuery conversion need

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure the code below 100% correct but it was doing the job and now need to convert for jQuery.

```
var count = 0.00;
var currency = "R$";

function doCount() {
    count = count + 1.99;
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = currency + parseFloat(count).toFixed(2).replace(/\./g, ',');
    var tim = setTimeout('doCount()', 60000); // increment every 60 seconds
}
doCount();
```

Comment: If you want it to happen every sixty seconds, use `setInterval()` once rather than creating a new timeout in each function call. You should also be passing a function reference (`setInterval(doCount, 60000)`) rather than a string (`setInterval('doCount()', 60000)`).

Comment: Firebug pops up doCount is not defined! any tip?

Comment: Make sure you're calling `setInterval(doCount, 60000)` **after** the function declaration for `doCount()`.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery is not a language, it is just a library to make your javascript simpler to write. If it's working like this, no need to convert it to jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

```
var count = 0.00; 
var currency = "R$";

function doCount() { 
  count = count + 1.99; 
  $("#number").html(
    currency + parseFloat(count).toFixed(2).replace(/./g, ',')
  ); 
  var tim = setTimeout('doCount()', 60000); // increment every 60 seconds 
} 
doCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval`

```
var count = 0.00,
    currency = "R$";

setInterval(function { 
    count = count + 1.99; 
    $("#number").html(
        currency + parseFloat(count).toFixed(2).replace(/./g, ',')
    ); 
}, 60*1000); // increment every 60 seconds
```

thanks to [@deadrunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837727/javascript-to-jquery-conversion-need/9837757#9837757)